# angular2 - clear input field value after click

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have problem with reseting my input values. I have search bar with filter functions. When i write some value it shows me list under it and i want to add function to this anchors, when i click some of them it routes me to another component and i want to clear the input value.

My code:

```
<div class="form">
            <input #query (keyup)="filter(query.value)" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
            <ng-container *ngIf="query.value">
              <div *ngFor="let f of filteredProducts">
                <a (click)="!query.value" [routerLink]="['/product-details/', f.category , f.$key]">{{ f.name }}</a>
              </div>
            </ng-container>
          </div>
```

i've tried to set this value to null or '' like:

```
(click)="query.value = ''"
```

Comment: you can use ng-model="searchAll" and call funciton  for set value to  null $scope.searchAll = null; checkout this link http://jsfiddle.net/nzPJD/

Comment: How is with angular2 ?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/dyCp5ZMKOkZvcsw4F8og?p=preview check out this link and same use ngmodal and set value to null

Comment: Try calling a function on click and in funtion first set the input value to blank and then navigate.

Comment: I can't have there any buttons, my event must be on <a> when i click some of a in list i need to clear input

Comment: @ManojBhardwaj add this to answers it works!

Comment: ok  @FreeStyle09 i added this as a answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://plnkr.co/edit/dyCp5ZMKOkZvcsw4F8og?p=preview check out this link and use ngmodal and set value to null

```
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..."  [(ngModel)]="searchValue">
  <button (click)="clearSearch()">Clear</button>
</div>


     export class App {
      searchValue:string = '';
     clearSearch() {
     this.searchValue = null;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Html

```
<div class="form">
        <input #query (keyup)="filter(query.value)" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
        <ng-container *ngIf="query.value">
          <div *ngFor="let f of filteredProducts">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)='myfun(f)'>{{ f.name }}</a>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
```

In class add

```
@ViewChild("query") input: ElementRef;

myfun(f) {

this.input.nativeElement.value = "";
this.router.navigate(['/product-details/', f.category , f.$key]");
}
```

Comment: this.input.nativeElement.value = ""; --> this code helped me to clear the textbox.                
 My code was:                                                                                                                   
   <input type="text" #myInput id="myInput" (input)="doSomething($event.target.value);">